# How to pass an environment variable to a binary program within a bash script?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have the following fragment of a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
... # commands
export var=3
./a.out # : execute a binary program using the environment variable "var"
... # commands
```

where the program `a.out` requires the value of the SHELL environment variable `var`. Could you please help me how to define `var` such that `a.out` should be able to use its value? The command `export var=3` doesn't work.

Comment: how are you accessing this environmental variable in your program. because `export var=3` is a legal syntax in bash

Comment: This is how you add `var` to the environment. If it doesn't work, the problem is in `a.out`, not your script.

Comment: If I use `export var=3` in prompt, then I execute `a.out`, then it runs properly, using `$var`, but if I do the same in a bash script, it cannot use `$var`.

Comment: How exactly are you confirming that `a.out` fails to use `var`?

Comment: The outputs of `a.out` are different in the two contexts (in prompt, in script).

Comment: @Roloka From what you've described, the difference in output has to be due to some other difference between running from a script vs. running from an interactive shell prompt. What that difference is, we can't really tell without more information.

Comment: Sounds like you might have more than one version of `a.out` and `PATH` differences might be the issue.  Its a bad idea to use `a.out` (the default C program name) exactly for this reason.  I suggest you recompile using the `-o` option, or just rename the binary file using `mv`.